# Identification topology and disjoint unions

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I was reading the book **Basic Topology** by **M.A. Armstrong** and I came across something I couldn't understand. I have uploaded the relevant pages- [image]

**(1)**  What  exactly is a *disjoint* union and what is the topology on it?

**(2)** Why is the function *j* continuous ?

**(3)**  The example related to *Figure 4.2*, is unclear to me. How does the subspace topology give a space homeomorphic to the circle , whereas the identification topology does not ?

Comment: There's nothing on the link.

Comment: This is how I understand disjoint unions: A disjoint union is a coproduct in $\mathbf{Set}$.

Comment: The link works for me.

Comment: I can't see it though. See the tutorial on how to add a picture onto the question itself.

Comment: That looks ugly how to put it in the middle, I mean closer to each other

Comment: @Sanath: If that's how you understand "disjoint union" then you might not understand it at all.

Comment: @AsafKaragila How is it that one understands it, then?

Comment: @Sanath: As the union of disjoint copies of the sets.

Comment: I looked up what Coproduct means in wikipedia, certainly beyound my current level of comprehension.

Comment: One definition of the disjoint union of $X$ and $Y$ is as the set $X\times\{0\}\cup Y\times \{1\}$ with $U$ being an open set in $X\sqcup Y$ if and only if $U=U_0\cup U_1$ where $U_0\subset X$ is open in $X$ and $U_1\subset Y$ is open in $Y$.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same questions while reading that particular page in Amstrong's book. It's a slight lack of clarity in an otherwise excellent book. Here is what I figured out:

A good introduction/explanation to/of disjoint union(s) is given in the Appendix (p. 145) of Lee's Introduction to Toplogical Manifolds. If you cannot get a copy of the book, I'd be happy to type in the relevant sentences from Lee's book. The important thing to understand is that the collection of sets in the disjoint union need not necessarily be disjoint, but still a disjoint union could be defined by "tagging" the index to each set. For example, it is possible to form a disjoint union consisting of "five copies of R", in which we may consider different copies to be disjoint from each other by tagging each element in each copy with elements from the set (1,2,3,4,5}.

A topology is defined on a disjoint union as follows: $O$ is an open set in the disjoint union $\sqcup X_\alpha$ if and only if $O$'s intersection with each $X_\alpha$ is open. This topology is called the disjoint union topology. From this definition it is clear that the inclusion map  $j: X_\alpha \rightarrow \sqcup_{\alpha}{X_\alpha}$ is continuous, since $j^{-1}(O) = O \cap X_{\alpha}$.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I figured out the problem quite a while ago. I got the copy of the book. Interesting...